# latex/tikz macro conditional

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm writing a latex macro which includes a tikz drawing, now I'd like to draw one path only if the optional parameter is set.

How can you interact from within tikz with the parameters given from latex?

something like this:

```
\newcommand{\myTikzDrawing}[1][default]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,1) -- (1,1);
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,0); %this line should only be drawn, if #1 is set to the default value
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `is if` key to introduce a conditional.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifTikZdrawthis
\tikzset{draw this/.is if=TikZdrawthis,draw this/.default=true}
\newcommand{\myTikzDrawing}[1][draw this=true]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
        \draw (0,1) -- (1,1);
        \ifTikZdrawthis
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,0); %this line should only be drawn, if #1 is set to the default value
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\myTikzDrawing
\bigskip

\myTikzDrawing[blue]
\bigskip

\myTikzDrawing[red,draw this]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good, would you just be so kind to show the dependency between the naming (I'm not quite sure, what has to have the same name and what you've just chosen to name the same ;)

Comment: @atticus The `/.is if` key handler is described on p. 989 of pgfmanual v3.1.5. The naming is such that skip the `if` in the beginning, i.e. `draw this/.is if=TikZdrawthis` links the Boolean `draw this` to the TeX `\if` `\ifTikZdrawthis`. There is also the `/.is choice` key handler, which allows you to go beyond Boolean yes/no choices.

Comment: Why is the second line not drawn in that case, when you pass only the option `blue` along? Don't you set with `draw this/.default=true` the key to a default value of true, so if the key is not set, it should be true by default?

Comment: @atticus I thought this is what you are asking for. The reason is that the if is set to false. The command is such that if you do not specify the optional argument, it will be `draw this=true` per the LaTeX mechanism `\newcommand{\myTikzDrawing}[1][draw this=true]{....`. That is, if you say `\myTikzDrawing[blue]`, you do *not* say `draw this=true` . If you want the opposite behavior, just set the initial value of `draw this` to true.

Comment: Using this line `\tikzset{draw this/.is if=TikZdrawthis,draw this/.initial=true,draw this/.default=true}` sadly does not work, the default is still false.

Comment: @atticus This is not what I said (but I admit/agree that the `/.initial` key can be confusing). I meant `\tikzset{draw this/.is if=TikZdrawthis,draw this/.default=true,
draw this}`. The `/.initial` key does something slightly different. It introduces a key which has some initial value. In this case, we have the key already, and we want just set it to true in the beginning.

Comment: Ah now it's working :+1

Comment: @atticus You asked: "Why is the second line not drawn in that case, when you pass only the option `blue` along? Don't you set with `draw this/.default=true` the key to a default value of true, so if the key is not set, it should be true by default? "  Be aware that the default is applied only when the key is used without providing a value. If the key is not used at all, then the default is not applied. And `\newif` initializes the `\if..`-switch to `\iffalse`. So if the key `draw this` is not applied at all, then `\ifTikZdrawthis` is `\iffalse`.

Comment: Oh, thanks, didn't know that