# latex/tikz latex macro specify node text when using the macro (with tikz keys)

Tags: tikz-pgf

this is some kind of an extension of [latex/tikz macro conditional set options for \draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544749/latex-tikz-macro-conditional-set-options-for-draw/544755#544755)

I've got something like this

```
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{cccdf1}

\newif\ifCond
\tikzset{
    cond/.is if=Cond,Cond/.default=false,
    bgCol/.is choice,
    bgCol/blue/.code={\tikzset{myrect/.style={fill=color1}}},
    bgCol/red/.code={\tikzset{myrect/.style={fill=red}}},
}

\newcommand{\myTikZdrawing}[1][Cond=false]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

        \ifCond
        \draw[myrect] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5) node[midway] {text};
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Now I'd like to specify with some tikz key the content of the node text when using the macro later on in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the value of a pgf key in some macro that you fill in the node. The pgf key can be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{cccdf1}

\newif\ifCond
\tikzset{
    Cond/.is if=Cond,Cond/.default=true,
    myrect/.style={},
    my text/.store in=\mytext,
    my text={A},
    bgCol/.is choice,
    bgCol/blue/.code={\tikzset{myrect/.style={fill=color1}}},
    bgCol/red/.code={\tikzset{myrect/.style={fill=red,draw=cyan,dashed}}},
}

\Condtrue
\newcommand{\myTikZdrawing}[1][Cond=false]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

        \ifCond
        \draw[myrect] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5) node[midway] 
        {\mytext};
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\myTikZdrawing
\bigskip

\myTikZdrawing[Cond]
\bigskip

\myTikZdrawing[Cond,bgCol=blue,my text=B]
\bigskip

\myTikZdrawing[Cond,bgCol=red,my text=C]
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want to "waste" a macro on this, you can work with `\pgfkeysvalueof` and the `/.initial` key handler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{cccdf1}

\newif\ifCond
\tikzset{
    Cond/.is if=Cond,Cond/.default=true,
    myrect/.style={},
    my text/.initial={A},
    bgCol/.is choice,
    bgCol/blue/.code={\tikzset{myrect/.style={fill=color1}}},
    bgCol/red/.code={\tikzset{myrect/.style={fill=red,draw=cyan,dashed}}},
}

\Condtrue
\newcommand{\myTikZdrawing}[1][Cond=false]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

        \ifCond
        \draw[myrect] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5) 
            node[midway] 
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my text}};
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\myTikZdrawing
\bigskip

\myTikZdrawing[Cond]
\bigskip

\myTikZdrawing[Cond,bgCol=blue,my text=B]
\bigskip

\myTikZdrawing[Cond,bgCol=red,my text=C]
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

The result is as above.

Comment: On the long run, if you produce many of these keys, you may want to start putting them in your own subdirectories.

Comment: Ok, looks like I'll have to learn this as well as checking if there is a way to get an `if` not checking a boolean but checking a tikz key for hits value. (I'm still new to tikz and it's just such a huge topic to learn)